# How best to allow SQL Agent Jobs to be edited and run by a team of developers, without handing out Sysadmin rights?

Tags: sql, ssms, microsoft

I'm trying to find or devise a way to allow a team of developers to be able to amend SQL Agent Job steps and schedules, but that doesn't involve Sysadmin rights for the devs. As I can't assign ownership of Agent jobs to a Group I need some sort of workaround.

So far I've come up with the following ideas

1. Create a Login to the server and a matching User in MSDB and Master. Use this account to own Agent Jobs. To allow amendments, GRANT EXECUTE ON [msdb].[dbo].sp_update_job, sp_update_jobstep and sp_update_jobschedule to a group containing the developers.

This allows them to submit amendments to any Agent Job by using the MSDB stored procedures

2. Create a Login / User as above, and make it owner of all the Agent Jobs. Then share the password with the developers.

Neither of these two scenarios are particularly secure for different reasons, but I'm trying to balance the needs of the security team versus the developers ability to perform their jobs - so a little pragmatism needs to be involved I think.

Are there any better ways to achieve this?

Comment: `the needs of the security team`...`Neither of these two scenarios are particularly secure for different reason`  So if the security team doesn't want sysadmin, why would #2 not be desirable or an alternative? And why would sysadmin even be discussed as an alternative if that were the case? And if #2 is not secure enough, what would be an example of a process/scenario that is secure?

Comment: Option 2 allows changes to be made with no audit trail, as there is no easy way of determining who was using the shared account. Also, sharing credentials is usually frowned upon for solid reasons.

Sysadmin is only being discussed becuase that is a common workaround for problems such as this. But again it's not ideal. A bit like giving Windows users Domain Admin rights so they can access a network share

Comment: `Option 2 allows changes to be made with no audit trail, as there is no easy way of determining who was using the shared account`. Then don't share accounts, have a separate account for each person. That doesn't seem very challenging. Most organizations have to provision multiple accounts in multiple systems anyway...

Comment: SQL can only allow one user to edit an agent job, but I want multiple people to be able to edit any job.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on this today and my solution to the problem was to create a Stored Procedure in a trustworthy database with EXECUTE AS OWNER, where the owner is sa.  I limit the scope of it by creating a new job Category and setting the category of any editable job to that category.  Then I grant EXECUTE permission to this new Stored Procedure to the developers.

This Stored Procedure changes the owner of the job (they specify their own name for example) and then they can edit it.  Once they are done they can change the owner back to 'sa' or whatever it previously was.

Of course it still has the potential for abuse, as the developer could edit the job in some nefarious way and then set it to run as sa.  But this could be mitigated perhaps by auditing who is changing the job owner and what the new job definition is, so there is some accountability.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.UpdateJobOwner
    @JobName NVARCHAR(128),
    @NewOwner NVARCHAR(128)
WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @JobId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER;
DECLARE @result int;

-- Get the Job ID based on the provided Job Name
SELECT  @JobId = job_id
FROM    msdb.dbo.sysjobs sj
JOIN    msdb.dbo.syscategories sc
ON      sc.category_id = sj.category_id
WHERE   sj.[name] = @JobName
AND     sc.[name] = N'Editable Agent Jobs'

-- Check if the job exists
IF @JobId IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    -- Update the job owner     
    EXEC @result = msdb.dbo.sp_update_job
        @job_id = @JobId,
        @owner_login_name = @NewOwner;

    IF (@result = 0) PRINT 'Job owner updated successfully.';
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Job not found. Please check the provided Job Name.';
END
END
GO
```

Of course the 'correct' procedure is not to allow developers to change agent jobs whenever they like, and to have any changes go through a Change Control process.   But the world isn't a perfect place and this will do the job for me, for now.